# Understanding details on Dapper objects and splits and maps in C# and .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dapper

I am looking at a new project and have a bug that needs fixing but have never used Dapper every (only read about it as I believe this site uses it). I am trying to understand a couple of things in the following code block below. The entire code block is listed initially for readability and then the questions are broken down below that with snippets from the code.

Code block:

```
_sql = "SELECT p.*, " +
             "s.SupplierId AS 'SplitOnSupplierId', s.*, " +
             "pd.ProductId AS 'SplitOnProductId', pd.* " +
        "FROM Parts p " +
        "JOIN Supplier s ON s.SupplierId = p.SupplierId " +
        "JOIN Productss pd ON pd.ProductId = " + productId + " " +
        "WHERE p.SupplierId = '" + supplierId + "' " +
          "AND p.PartModel = '" + partModel + "'";

var result = new List<Parts>();

try
{
    using (_myDb = DapperConnect.GetOpenConnection())
    {
        result = _myDb.Query<Parts, Supplier, Product, Parts>(_sql,
                    commandType: CommandType.Text,
                    map: (p, s, pd) =>
                    {
                        p.Supplier = s;
                        p.Product = pd;
                        return p;
                    },
                    splitOn: "SplitOnSupplierId,SplitOnProductId").ToList();

        return result.Count == 0 ? null : result[0];
    };
}
catch
{
    return null;
}
```

Code with fragments and questions:

1. The `_spl` query just gets all the data needed to make the objects in the mapping section below.
   I need to go through this an understand the nature of what is needed, so that question can be ignored.

   ```
        _sql = "SELECT p.*, " +
                "s.SupplierId AS 'SplitOnSupplierId', s.*, " +
                "pd.ProductId AS 'SplitOnProductId', pd.* " +
                "FROM Parts p " +
                "JOIN Supplier s ON s.SupplierId = p.SupplierId " +
                "JOIN Productss pd ON pd.ProductId = " + productId + " " +
                "WHERE p.SupplierId = '" + supplierId + "' " +
                "AND p.PartModel = '" + partModel + "'";

        var result = new List<Parts>();

        try
        {
            using (_myDb = DapperConnect.GetOpenConnection())
            {
   ```
2. I do not understand why `Parts` is in this list twice and in general terms what does this line do?

   ```
               result = _myDb.Query<Parts, Supplier, Product, Parts>(
                   _sql,
                   commandType: CommandType.Text,
   ```
3. I think I see that the query above is putting all the results from `_sql` into a list of `Parts` objects
   with their relationships to `Supplier` and `Product`?

   ```
                   map: (p, s, pd) =>
                   {
                       p.Supplier = s;
                       p.Product = pd;
                       return p;
                   },
   ```
4. I am not quite sure what or how this line below works.

   ```
                   splitOn: "SplitOnSupplierId,SplitOnProductId").ToList();

               return result.Count == 0 ? null : result[0];
           };
       }
       catch
       {
           return null;
       }
   ```

As I said before I have never used Dapper in any sort of way and this is the first day I am truly reading about it. Any help is
greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dapper doesn't know about your database relations, so you need to tell it how to map the data.

The data comes as a set of rows and the mapping is saying what to do with each row. The generic query (Q2) needs to know what parts to split the row into and which type is should return. In your case it says "split into `Parts`, `Supplier` and `Product` and return `Parts`". That's why `Parts` is there twice.

The mapping part in Q3 gets your three objects `p`, `s` and `d` and establishes the relations. This should return something of type `Parts`, and so it does. The last bit (Q4) is about where to cut the data row into the three objects and it mentions two data columns that should be used as separators. So everything before SplitOnSupplierId is Parts, the next bit is Supplier until you reach SplitOnProductId and the rest is Product.

Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. You should use parameters instead of building the SQL query as text. It could also increase performance. Your code would look something like this:

```cs
_sql = @"SELECT p.*, s.SupplierId AS 'SplitOnSupplierId', s.*, 
            pd.ProductId AS 'SplitOnProductId', pd.* 
         FROM Parts p JOIN Supplier s ON s.SupplierId = p.SupplierId
            JOIN Productss pd ON pd.ProductId = p.ProductId 
         WHERE p.SupplierId = @SupplierId
            AND p.ProductId = @ProductId
            AND p.PartModel = @PartModel";

try
{
    using (_myDb = DapperConnect.GetOpenConnection())
    {
        var result = _myDb.Query<Parts, Supplier, Product, Parts>(_sql,
                    commandType: CommandType.Text,
                    map: (p, s, pd) =>
                    {
                        p.Supplier = s;
                        p.Product = pd;
                        return p;
                    },
                    new {SupplierId = supplierId , ProductId = productId , PartModel = partModel }, 
                    splitOn: "SplitOnSupplierId,SplitOnProductId").ToList();

        return result.Count == 0 ? null : result[0];
    };
}
catch
{
    return null;
}
```

You could also use QueryFirstOrDefault or QuerySingleOrDefault to have only one result returned.

Comment: So is the split columns counted in one or the other (like before or after column sections) or just used as a split and not included in either?

Comment: The splitOn is part of the "next" section, so the cut appears before the column.

Comment: Thanks that's what i need clarity on